# Modify existing plugins in Nativescript app

Tags: plugins, nativescript

Hi I would like to make small modifications to an existing plugin (Nativescript-BitmapFactory) because rotating in ios rotates the image out of view. I modified the code in the mode_modules\nativescript-BitmapFactory directory but when i run to ios the original file gets pulled from "https://registry.npmjs.org...   Please advise.

**I changed the rotate-function in the BitmapFactory plugin and this works perfectly !!!! alse the resize plugin was altered.**

Comment: It won't pull it from NPM until it's necessary, like the module itself is missing in the path. Still I would suggest copy the entire folder to your project itself, remove the dependency from `package.json` and make the changes you want then require the plugin using relative path to your project. So even if you do a clean build, you won't  have to modify it again.

Answer (score 0):

The rotate function in the NativeScript-Bitmapfactory does not work for me. So i put the bitmap-factory plugin in my project and changed the require statements to include the correct path... works like a dream !